# Changing theme on ggsurvplot - error: Don't know how to add ggtheme to a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with the requisite columns in surv_rate. This is what I am running, it is based off of examples from: http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/survminer/reference/ggsurvplot.html

```
fit2 <- survfit(Surv(YearsToStatus, VitalStatus) ~ PR_statusIndex + HER2_statusIndex + ER_statusIndex,
                data = surv_rate)

ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(fit2, data = surv_rate, ggtheme = theme_bw)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Don't know how to add ggtheme to a plot
```

The reason that I am trying this is that no grid lines are displaying in the `ggsurv` plot.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me, additionally for reference I am fairly new to R.

Comment: You need `ggtheme = theme_bw()` (note the parentheses).

Comment: @aosmith Thank you so much!! Post an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme has to be written as a function like you would if in **ggplot2**, so the theme name needs to end with a pair of parentheses.

```
ggtheme = theme_bw()
```